# Доступ к полям родительского класса (Рефлексия) - C#

Tags: c#

Есть вот такая конструкция, напишу упрощённо:

```
public partial class A : UserControl {

public class B : A {}

    public A(){
        var cmbList = C.SelectllControlsByType(this, typeof(ComboBox));
    }
}

public static class C {
    /// <summary>
    /// Выбрать контролы заданого типа
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="controlType"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static List<Control> SelectllControlsByType(Control rootControl, Type selectionControlType) {
         return (from field in rootControl.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
                where field.FieldType == selectionControlType
                select field.GetValue(rootControl) as Control).ToList();
    }
}
```

Если инстанциируем контрол класса `A`, то метод `SelectllControlsByType` отрабатывает корректно и возвращает (к примеру) список из трёх комбобоксов, которые есть на этом контроле. А если создаем тот же контрол, но через дочерний класс: `new A.B()`, то метод возвращает пустой список, хотя комбобоксы по прежнему существуют на этом контроле.

Т.е. я так понимаю `GetType().GetFields` в методе `SelectllControlsByType` пытаются взять поля класса `B`, а у него естественно их нет, они есть только у `А`.

Как сделать так, чтобы метод отрабатывал корректно в обоих случаях?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Проблема в том, что [метод `GetFields`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ztex2dc(v=vs.110).aspx) возвращает закрытые поля лишь текущего класса, но не базовых классов. Поэтому вы закономерно получаете (пустой) список полей класса `B.A`.

Вам нужно подняться вверх по дереву наследования:

```
static List<Control> SelectllControlsByType(Control rootControl, Type selectionControlType)
{
    IEnumerable<Type> GetTypeChain(Type from, Type to)
    {
        for (var t = from; t != to; t = t.BaseType)
            yield return t;
    }

    IEnumerable<FieldInfo> GetPrivateFields(Type t) =>
        t.GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

    var allFields = GetTypeChain(rootControl.GetType(), typeof(Control))
                        .SelectMany(GetPrivateFields);

    return (from field in allFields
            where field.FieldType == selectionControlType
            select field.GetValue(rootControl) as Control).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Да, я тоже полагал, что нужно как-то получить доступ к родительскому классу, но как это сделать не знал. Теперь знаю, думаю ещё не раз пригодится. Большое спасибо за ответ! Завтра на работе опробую. ))

Comment: @Иван: Пожалуйста! Буду рад, если пригодится.

Comment: Ещё раз большое спасибо! Всё работает как надо. Только немного непонятен синтаксис определения метода GetTypeChain внутри метода  SelectllControlsByType и ещё   IEnumerable<FieldInfo> GetPrivateFields(Type t) =>
        t.GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);  Думаю, возможно это опечатка. Но ничего разнёс по 3-м отдельным методом и всё отлично.

Comment: @Иван: Это вложенные функции, [синтаксис C# 7](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#local-functions). Если у вас Visual Studio 2017, должно работать как есть.

Comment: Ясно. У меня проект в VS 2010 на NetFramework 3.5, а это C# 4, по моему. Поэтому синтаксис C# 7 мне особо не знаком, из-за этого и бросился в глаза. Но спасибо, буду знать.